# How to include offsets of 2 variable in one linear model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, biostatistics, poisson-regression, offset

I've been conducting some research on recruitment of fish and fish survival in estuaries. I'm analysing recruitment and mortality against environmental variables such as temperature and river flow. The fish are categorised into age categories and are being analysed separately.

I've been analysing how environmental variables affect recruitment of fish to the estuary using a negative binomial GLM, including the human effort as an offset.

Now I've come to analyse how many fish die over winter and I'm struggling to understand how to standardise this using the effort.

For example, I have number of 1 year old fish caught in 2015, and number of 2 year old fish caught in 2016. Both of these have an associated effort attached to them. Ideally I'd be able to do

```
((1 year old/effort)-(2 year old/effort)) = mortality
```

and run models comparing mortality against environmental variables but I'm confused about what model I can run using that data (which aren't integers). Or is there any way I can run a Poisson/Quasi-poisson model incorporating the offset for both yr1 and yr2 fish.

Comment: Please say more about what you mean by the "human effort" and its expected association with fish numbers. And do you have separate environmental variable values for the 2 years?

Comment: The human effort is purely the amount of time spent fishing. Under normal circumstances the number of fish caught would be displayed as ‘catch per unit effort’ (CPUE), but for the GLM its best to include the effort as an offset. 

The env. data is the same for each age of fish as they were caught in the same location. There’s 15 years worth of data, so 15 totals of fish and associated variables. 

To analyse overwinter mortality I need to do age 1 CPUE - age 2 CPUE, to give mortality, then test mortality against the env. variables. What sort of test I can use to compare non-integer data

Comment: Please provide the number of fish in typical samples. Also, your formula suggests that you care about mortality in terms of absolute numbers. Is that correct, or are you interested in a mortality rate? Are you only comparing 1-year-old and 2-year-old fish that are caught each year, or does this go on to many age comparisons in any 1 year? If so, is there an upper limit? Is there any evidence that fish of different ages differ in their probability of being caught per unit effort?

Comment: Please provide the extra information as an edit to the original post. Not everybody reads comments!